# CSS Counters - used with the content property only?

Tags: css

According to the spec, can/will CSS counters only be used in conjunction with the `content` property?

```
* { content: counter(mycounter) "! "; counter-increment: mycounter }
```

Or can/will they also be used with other properties, such as (random example) `padding`?

```
/*
    is this possible?
    is this supposed to be possible?
*/
* { padding:counter(mycounter)px; }
```

Lastly, if that is a feature of CSS, to what extent is it implemented in browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CSS2.1, the [`counter()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters) is indeed defined for use with the `content` property only; you cannot use counters to specify numeric values for other properties.

Comment: I find the link mildly confusing: while the title of the document is "*CSS3* Values and Units" the section you cite states "In *CSS2.1*, the values of counters can only be referred to from the 'content' property." I assume this means it will be unchanged in CSS3?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: I've rewritten my answer to link to the CSS2.1 spec instead. Beyond CSS2.1, it looks like `counter()` has been moved to [another module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists).